# Mirroring Terminal on Linux

Tags: linux, terminal

When giving a talk I usually use two screens: One is the wall showing the presentation to the audience, the other one is my Laptop screen with a mirror of the presentation, my speakernotes etc. 
During the talks I pretty often do demos using a terminal. This requires that
I turn around to check at the wall if everything works correctly. To avoid this I would like to have two terminal window, one on my laptop screen where I am typing and a mirror of it which is shown to the audience at the second screen. How can I do this?

Comment: 2 shells both attached to the same tmux session ?

Comment: A simple `script -f dump.txt` in one terminal and `tail -f dump.txt` in the other can also work as a one-way mirror.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look to the **screen** program. It does perfectly what you are trying to do. The following link gives a simple example of screen usage:

Start a new screen session with session name:

```
screen -S <name>
```

list running sessions/screens:

```
screen -ls
```

Attach to a running session:

```
screen -x
```

Attach to a running session with name:

```
screen -r session_name
```

**Screen quick reference**: http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference

**More links**:

https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Comment: The relevant option would be `screen -x`, I think.

Comment: Yes, I added some basic commands and the quick reference